# How to stop a video in a scene from playing after i move to another scene in flash?

Tags: flash, video, adobe, flash-cc

I have 2 scenes, both with buttons linking both scenes together. But I encounter a problem when moving from scene 1 to scene 2. The video playing in scene 1 continue to play after i have when on to scene 2 to view another video. Is there a way to stop the previous video?

Here are my code in Adobe Flash CC action script.

Button 1 in scene 1

```js
button_1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Scene_1ToScene2);

function Scene_1ToScene2(event: MouseEvent): void {
 gotoAndPlay(1, "Scene 2");
 stop();
}
```

Button 2 in scene 2

```js
button_2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Scene_2ToScene1);

function Scene_2ToScene1(event: MouseEvent): void {
 gotoAndPlay(1, "Scene 1");
 stop();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add in

`Video_001.stop();`

"Video_001" is the instance name of the video.

Answer (score 0):

Call stop() before calling gotoAndPlay(). That must help.

Comment: i gotten the same result

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your video a name Eg.[image]

After that go the actionscript side and use this code

```
button_1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Scene_1ToScene2);

function Scene_1ToScene2(event: MouseEvent): void {
flv.Stop(); 
gotoAndPlay(1, "Scene 2");

}
```